# OSError about 'fontconfig-1' after install 'fontconfig' on mac OS ventura on rosetta

Tags: homebrew, macos-ventura, fontconfig

I'm trying to run django migrate with iTerm that is running on rosetta,
my OS is mac OS 13.0.1 Ventura.

When I've run `python manage.py migrate` command, I got `OSError: ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'fontconfig-1'` error on both iTerm terminals (arch arm64 and i386).
I checked `arm64` and `i386` results when i typed `arch` command on each terminals.

I already installed `fontconfig` package with `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew` and `/usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew` both terminals. But I don't know why I got this error.

I also can't install `fontconfig-1` that is appeared in error message. Are `fontconfig` and `fontconfig-1` different packages?

I may have made a basic simple mistake because it's first time using the m1 but I can't solve my problem.

```py
from ctypes.util import find_library
print(find_library('fontconfig-1')) # None
print(find_library('fontconfig')) # /usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.dylib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `WeasyPrint` problem.
I didn't install `libffi` package on i386 terminal.
My alias link of brew on i386 terminal was `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew` so I changed it to `/usr/local/bin/brew`.

and I reinstall `libffi` package and I solved it.